# How to create Azure Functions in 2 different language(C#, node.js) under the same project vs 2017?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am struggling to find the way to have 2 Azure functions in different language(C# and node.js) in Azure functions Project vs 2017.
Is there a way to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible to get those 2 different projects deployed under the same resource? So, the 2 project doesn't replace the functions created by first project? @Mikhail

Comment: I want to create functions with  2 differnt languages (C#, nodejs) but this seems to be not possible. @Mikhail

Comment: It is possible, e.g. inside the portal with scripts, but not supported by VS tooling I think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

This method is invalid for v2 function(runtime ~2) because now it's required to use single language in one function app. See [announcement](https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements/issues/129).

---

> So, the 2 project doesn't replace the functions created by first project?

Do you mean that you found some functions are replaced after new project being deployed to Azure?
Normally they won't be replaced unless functions in new project has same function names as ones already deployed.

> create Azure Functions in 2 different language(C#, node.js) under one VS project

@Mikhail is right, VS doesn't provide ways for using js Azure function. No template and debug support for now.

But if you just want to run and deploy them together using VS, with no need to debug nodejs function, there's a workaround.

Generally speaking, you have to manually add nodejs function folder structure to VS project as below.

[image]

A folder named after your js function includes `function.json` and `xxx.js` file. If you have some packages installed by npm, also add `package.json` and `node_modules` folder.

`function.json`, `xxx.js` and `package.json` should be set as `Copy if newer`, so that they can be included in output dir like c# complied dll.

Not need to include `node_modules` locally, function host will locate them automatically. While after deploying to azure, you need to visit kudu(`https://{functionappname}.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole`). Execute `npm install` in console under `wwwroot` folder to install packages in `package.json`.

And [some function templates](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-templates/tree/dev/Functions.Templates/Templates) if needed.