# Can I use both dotnet and node in Azure Functions 2.0?

Tags: c#, node.js, azure, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

As Durable Functions JS API is limited by now, I wonder can I write my orchestration code with C# Scripts and my activity functions with node in Azure Functions 2.0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We're about to publish a v2 Functions release that removes the ability to run multiple languages in a single Function app. Going forward, all functions within a Function app must be written in the same language. (Note that v1 Function apps will not be affected by this.)

We're aiming to announce General Availability of Durable Functions JS later this year, which will include the rest of the API. The workaround we recommend at present is similar to what's [documented here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable-functions-types-features-overview#cross-function-app-communication) In your case, you could expose some JavaScript APIs over HTTP and have C# activity functions invoke them from the Function app that contains your C# orchestrator.

Comment: Thanks for response. Can you provide any accurate timeline on Durable Functions JS API GA?

Comment: The plan is to have the JS features GA by this fall, alongside the GA of Functions v2. I can't be more specific than that at this time.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

New release has published, function app requires single language right now. So this method is no longer valid.

---

You probably are talking about this [limit](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-js#api-implementation-checklist) as in JS some C# API is not implemented yet and some won't be implemented.

We can call JS Activity in C# orchestration function. Just test with a simple activity returns string, works as expected.

For local development, `FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME`(in local.settings.json) specifies our function app language worker, only functions corresponding to this runtime can be recognized by function host. For example, in dotnet runtime, js functions are ignored.

1. Delete `FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME` and the host is able to work with different languages.
2. Add one folder named after your Activity function to function app folder, containing function.json and index.js. See illustration below(In VSCode, similar to [VS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50737699/how-to-create-azure-functions-in-2-different-languagec-node-js-under-the-sam/50755048#50755048)).

   [image: VSCode illustration]
3. Add CopyToOutputDirectory action to functionappname.csproj.

   ```
   <ItemGroup>
   ...
       <None Update="MyJsActivity\index.js">
         <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
       </None>
       <None Update="MyJsActivity\function.json">
       <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
       </None>
   </ItemGroup>
   ```
4. Feel free to install node module if needed, remember to add CopyToOutputDirectory action for package.json, so that we can install modules using it during deployment.

Besides on portal there's no such equivalent setting right now, host offers different language workers by default. After deployment, everything should work.